# How can I access to __annotations__ of parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Is there any way to access to the typing __**annotations** __ of the parent class?

In the above example, the class `Student` inherit from class `Person`, but It does not contains the typing annotations from the `Person` class.

```py
class Person:
    name: str
    address: str

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__annotations__)


class Student(Person):
    year: int


person = Person()
# {'name': <class 'str'>, 'address': <class 'str'>}

student = Student()
# {'year': <class 'int'>}
# HERE I would expect the name and the address props
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.__annotations__`, in the absence of an instance attribute named `__annotations__`, is equivalent to `type(self).__annotations__`. Since `Student.__annotations__` is defined, there is no reason to look for `Person.__annotations__`. You would need to check each class in your MRO. The easiest way to do that is to define a single class method in some base class (or make it an external function that isn't associated with any single class).

```
class Person:
    name: str
    address: str

    @classmethod
    def get_annotations(cls):
        d = {}
        for c in cls.mro():
            try:
                d.update(**c.__annotations__)
            except AttributeError:
                # object, at least, has no __annotations__ attribute.
                pass
        return d

    def __init__(self):
        print(self.get_annotations())


class Student(Person):
    year: int
```

Comment: Beware, in cases where there is disagreement between two classes in the MRO, this will give priority to the annotation that occurs *last* in the MRO, whereas Python class inheritance usually gives priority to the one that comes *first*!  (To fix this, you might reverse the MRO, and take care to preserve a copy of this class's own original annotations to re-update it with as a final step.  Or use the simpler approach I suggest in my own answer.)  

Also beware that Python docs say that you shouldn't alter `__annotations__` though they don't say why not to.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the answer I would have liked to have seen when a Google search brought me here.

```py
from collections import ChainMap

def all_annotations(cls) -> ChainMap:
    """Returns a dictionary-like ChainMap that includes annotations for all 
       attributes defined in cls or inherited from superclasses."""
    return ChainMap(*(c.__annotations__ for c in cls.__mro__ if '__annotations__' in c.__dict__) )
```

Unlike @chepner's approach, this correctly handles cases where multiple superclasses provide different annotations for the same attribute name (which is often inadvisable, but can be fine, e.g. when a subclass gives an attribute with a more specific annotation).  @chepner's approach will give priority to the annotation that occurs *last* in the method resolution order (MRO), whereas Python's class inheritance generally gives priority to whichever class comes *first* in that order.  (If you did want to use @chepner's approach, you'd probably do better to update annotations in the *reverse* of the MRO, taking care not to accidentally lose track of any annotations defined in this class.)

Comment: I'm not altering any existing `__annotations__` attribute, only collecting values in a new `dict`. (The point about reversing priority based on position in the MRO is valid.)

Comment: You're right that your approach doesn't alter existing `__annotations__`.  I removed that mistaken claim from my answer. Sorry I misread it.

Comment: With Python 3.10 it is better to use `inspect.get_annotations(c)` instead of `c.__annotations__`. It will also remove the need for `if '__annotations__' in c.__dict__` part.

Comment: Or even better just use `typing.get_type_hints()` and stop re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner without additional imports:

```py
def _get_annotated_attributes(cls) -> Set[str]:
    return {
        key
        for c in cls.mro() if hasattr(c, '__annotations__')
        for key in c.__annotations__
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a built in function for that: [typing.get_type_hints()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints)

> This is often the same as `obj.__annotations__`. In addition, forward references encoded as string literals are handled by evaluating them in globals and locals namespaces. For a class C, return a dictionary constructed by merging all the `__annotations__` along `C.__mro__` in reverse order.